# How to calculate angle beetween current direction and GPS point

Tags: java, android, geometry, android-gps

I have 2 points (Android Location objects): current location and target location. Also I have a direction (in degrees) of my device.

[image]

I wanna calculate an angle between target location and direction. How to do it properly?

I receiving location from FusedLocationProvider (if it's matter).
Now i just use

`float requiredAngle = Math.abs(location.getBearing() - 180 - target.bearingTo(location));`

`float angleBetween = Math.abs(requiredAngle - location.getBearing());`
and it's returns incorrect angle.

I think I should caclate the difference between true north and magnetic north and add device direction. Then use currentPosition.bearingTo(target), and subtract device direction from bearing.

Comment: Is this a 2d or a 3d field ? What is X,Y and Z then we would be able to provide an formula to this question

Comment: It's 3D field. I have GPS coordinates: latitude and longitude of point on Earth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This angle called **relative bearing**.

Register listeners to Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR, Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER, Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD.
Like:

```
sensorManager.registerListener(listener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

Then make a listener for this:

```
private float[] gravity;
private float[] geomagnetic;
private float[] R = new float[9];
private float[] I = new float[9];    

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        gravity = sensor.values(); // Just save the values
    }

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
        geomagnetic = sensor.values();
    }

    if (SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, gravity, geomagnetic)) { // If something is wrong (like device is in free fall)
        float orientation[] = new float[3];
        SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
        // Now you have values from -PI to PI
        float heading;
        if (R[0] > 0) { // R[0] is heading
            heading = R[0] * 180 / PI;
        } else { // -PI, eq. from South to West to North
            heading = (Math.abs(R[0]) * 180 / PI) * 2;
        }

        float relativeBearing = location.bearingTo(target) - heading;
        if (relativeBearing < 0) {
            relativeBearing = 360 + relativeBearing;
        }
    }
}
```

Documentation:
[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager#getRotationMatrix(float[],%20float[],%20float[],%20float[])](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager#getRotationMatrix(float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D))
[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager#getOrientation(float[],%20float[])](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager#getOrientation(float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D))

Answer (score 0):

In that case you could have a look on this article : https://onlinemschool.com/math/library/vector/angl/

1. calculate dot product of vectors
2. calculate vectors magnitude
3. calculate the angle between these 2 vectors

Formula for angle between vector A and vector B:
cosine(alpha) = dotProductAB / (magnitudeA * magnitudeB)